# Change number of x ticks on time series using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, graphing

I'm trying to plot a time series `x_output` that looks like this:

```
              timestamp   city wait_time weekday     time
    2015-07-14 09:00:00 Boston       1.6 Tuesday 09:00:00
    2015-07-14 09:01:00 Boston       1.8 Tuesday 09:00:00
    2015-07-14 09:02:00 Boston       2.4 Tuesday 09:00:00
    2015-07-14 09:03:00 Boston       2.9 Tuesday 09:00:00
    2015-07-14 09:04:00 Boston       4.5 Tuesday 09:00:00
    2015-07-14 09:05:00 Boston       5.6 Tuesday 09:00:00
```

Here's how I'm plotting it:

```
brks <- seq(1, length(x_output$timestamp), 10)
brks_labels <- x_output[brks, ]

p <- ggplot(x_output, aes(x=as.character(timestamp), y=wait_time, group=city)) + geom_line(aes(color=city), size=1.5) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1), legend.position = "bottom") + labs(x=NULL, y="Waiting time (minutes)") + scale_x_discrete(breaks = brks, labels = brks_labels)
print(p)
```

I have to use `x_output$timestamp` as a character (ie. categorical variable) because otherwise, ggplot2 thinks it's continuous and includes white blank areas that have no values.

For some reason however, `scale_x_discrete` does not seem to be working. I believe I got the input for breaks right, however, the labels now aren't showing. Does anyone know why? Here's what plots:

[image]

I'm trying to simply have the labels appear every 10 timestamps on the x-axis (which is why I put the breaks into an array as `brks`).

Comment: Would be good to have a reproducible example - in your example data all the wait times are NA so it's hard for us to make any sort of plot. If it's easier, just generate some dummy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your breaks have to be the same type as your `aes(x=`, i.e. `scale_x_discrete(breaks=x_output$timestamp[brks])` works.

However be aware that converting your timestamp to categorical like this can be inaccurate on the timescale then - if a timestamp skipped by 2 minutes and the rest skipped by 1 this wouldn't be reflected on your graph.

I think you're better off keeping X as a datetime, and using `+ scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("10 mins"))`. If you have multiple windows of time separated by expanses of no data, you could use a variable to indicate which 'window' each row belongs to, and `facet_wrap` to plot the windows side-by-side, which would let you skip the gaps while preserving x-axis scale. E.g. you could `facet_wrap` by `weekday` if your data was only for a particular window each day.

Comment: This worked! Thanks. One final question (which I can open up a new question for as well): do you know how to set the x-range limits on ggplot2 for timestamps? It shows me 24hrs on the plots but I need only 9am-6pm. I feel it's something like `scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hour")), limits = c(as.POSIXct("9:00"), as.POSIXct("18:00"))` but I'm not sure how to just specify a time without a date on the timestamp

Comment: date_breaks() was deprecated. Use breaks_width() now.